# Which JUNG algorithms are appropriate here?

Tags: java, algorithm, jung

So I have been set the task of making a program that takes in a wide set of text files, and calculating strange communication patterns in that set. Basically I think that we need to work out extremes of frequency of communication, along with clustering groups of people together that communicate very often.

As well as that I'd like to create a 'social network style' graph that shows who communicates with everyone who, and graphs of the form 'number of emails over time'.

Additionally, any other ideas of types of graphs to include would be great, though my main predicament is which algorithms to use for this.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem like a specific java question, since an algorithm is more like an idea, independent from a certain programming language. So maybe [MathExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable for the question? The "type of graph" is also no direct programming problem, more that of the visualisation. I think, that MathExchange could be helpful for that as well.

Comment: There are many different graph clustering algorithms out there; JUNG includes some of them.  The rest of your question is pretty vague, though: "work out extremes", "ideas of types of graphs to include".  It sounds like you may want to talk to someone who knows about social network analysis; you should discuss your overall goals with them and clarify what data you have to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I decided on using K Means Clustering, alongside Barycenter.